# Oracle External Job Error ORA-27369: job of type EXECUTABLE failed with exit code: Not owner

Tags: shell, oracle10g

i have an Oracle scheduler job that run an executable shell script in Solaris environment. Job runs every 2nd Sunday each month, it runs in status failed in Scheduler Job log with error code : ORA-27369

here is my shell script :

```
#!/bin/bash
ORACLE_HOME=/app/oracle/10g; 
export ORACLE_HOME;
ORACLE_SID=IBSDB; 
export ORACLE_SID;

edate=`date "+%Y%m%d"`; export edate;

$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus "/ as sysdba" @/app/oracle/script/alter_all_index.sql
```

this shell script run sqlplus and execute alter_all_index.sql. alter_all_index.sql creates 2 file via spool command. first is ALTER_INDEX_REBUILD.sql, this file contain query to rebuild all index. and the second file is LOG_ALTER_INDEX_REBUILD.txt to store any error occurs while executing ALTER_INDEX_REBUILD.sql here is the code of alter_all_index.sql

```
set wrap off
set linesize 1000
set feedback off
set pagesize 0
set verify off

set termout off

spool ALTER_INDEX_REBUILD.sql;
prompt set linesize 1000
prompt set pagesize 0
prompt spool LOG_ALTER_INDEX_REBUILD.txt

PROMPT ------------------ START FROM HERE ---------------

--prompt varID nvarchar2(40):=sys_guid();;
--prompt insert into PCB_AGCM.QUERY_HK_MONITOR (ID,  TASK_NAME, START_TIME, END_TIME, STATUS) values(varID, 'REBUILD INDEX', to_char(sysdate, 'Dy DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), null, 'STARTING');;
--prompt commit;;

prompt ------------------ execute GCM_AGCM --------------

select 'ALTER INDEX '||owner||'.'||INDEX_NAME||' REBUILD ONLINE;'  
from all_indexes where owner like 'PCB_AGCM%';

PROMPT ------------------ END OF SCRIPT ----------------------

--prompt update PCB_AGCM.QUERY_HK_MONITOR set end_time=to_char(sysdate, 'Dy DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), status='COMPLETED' where ID = varID;;
prompt commit;;

prompt exec PCB_AGCM.GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS();;
PROMPT /

PROMPT ------------------- END OF SCRIPT ----------------------

prompt spool off

SPOOL OFF;

@@ALTER_INDEX_REBUILD.sql
```

before the job run, both ALTER_INDEX_REBUILD.sql and LOG_ALTER_INDEX_REBUILD.txt are exist generated from previous manual run. 
when i tested via Oracle Scheduler Job. first it run well, and i look its session through TOAD->session browser, it works well, query rebuild index was running, but after the last index done, job ended with error ORA-27369: job of type EXECUTABLE failed with exit code: Not owner.

i examine all the script. both ALTER_INDEX_REBUILD.sql and LOG_ALTER_INDEX_REBUILD.txt is not updated, Spool command will create and replace if existed by default, their last modification date is 13 April 2013. it should have changed into 9 May 2013.

i come with a conclusion, that there is a problem with spool command, but i got no idea how to solve this, i thought that it might concern their ownership and permission but both file owned by oracle. anyone got any idea why and how to solve this ?

[image: ownership and permission]

i have browsed about ORA-27369 but none gives me any hints so far.

sincerely

Answer (score 2):

There are a few Big Questions to ask about this:

- Why run as an external job a sql*plus script that you could just run as a pl/sql procedure? As a general rule, if you do not need to involve the operating system in a task, then don't do it. Code kept on the file system is not backed up with the database and is more prone to error through connection problems or Some Damn Fool Just Deleting It.

Code like the index rebuild ought to be a procedure with code such as:

```
for indexes in (select   owner,
                         index_name
                from     all_indexes
                where    owner like 'PCB_AGCM%'
                order by owner,
                         table_name)
loop
  sql := 'alter index '||indexes.owner||'.'||indexes.index_name||' rebuild online';

  execute immediate sql;
end loop
```

- Why are you regularly rebuilding all of your indexes? If you get an immediate measurable benefit to it then it's because you have compacted your indexes, but you're then going to incur more overhead through the index growing back to it's natural size. See many entries on Richard Foote's [blog](http://richardfoote.wordpress.com/) for more information.

Comment: @david-aldridge awesome! i am new in DBA world David, lot to learn.

Comment: Funny story -- I once lost a complete directory hierarchy including code and date without backup when a systems monitoring team applied previously unannounced corporate standards to a unix host. "I think your team might have chosen the wrong method for engaging the technical community in their discussion", we said, laughingly.

Comment: @HermanPlaniGinting You're in the right place, my friend. See http://asktom.oracle.com and everyone on Richard's blogroll.

Comment: @david-aldridge actually, there is another process run before rebuilding indexes. its a housekeeping procedure, deleting all transaction data that is more than 3 month in ages. but i ll try to propose your advice.

Comment: How often does the script run?

Comment: once a month, every 2nd Sunday each month

Comment: How long does the index rebuild take?

Comment: around 2 hours . depends on data size that can be vary each month

Comment: I'd try not doing it, or delaying it for a couple of days after the deletion -- just run the analyse of course. Don't tell the user community you're changing anything thoughh, because they'll start seeing phantom problems even if nothing has changed. Is this standard edition?

Comment: 10g Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bit

Comment: the procedure flows like this, housekeeping go first, then rebuild indexes and last gather stat. 
what is your concerns for not doing it or delaying it? 
the user community just know that there is data maintenance each second Sunday at 5 am each month. so if they would like to have a print out of their transaction prior to last 3 month, they should have it done before that date.

Comment: no my concern was that if you tell them you're not doing a particular something that you think aids performance then they'll find phantom performance problems. if you don't tell them and they don't notice then don't do the index rebuild

Comment: i see.
rebuild indexes procedure comes with idea that when a great amount of data is being deleted, indexes should also be rebuilt since previous indexes are no longer valid in data perspective. correct my if im wrong

Comment: There will be gaps in the index, but you'll almost certainly reuse them for new data over the next month anyway.just keep the statistics up to date. There are only very few circumstances where the gaps would not be reused.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, external programs launched by DBMS_SCHEDULER run as a low-privileged user account (usually nobody, see [Oracle forums](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=393942)).

To debug this issue, can you:

- run a simple script that outputs the UID
- check whether this user is allowed to create / overwrite files in /app/oracle/script/

Also, I'd recommend either specifying the absolute path for your SPOOL file instead of just the file name, or using `cd` before your SQL/Plus call to ensure the SPOOL file is created in the correct directory.

Comment: Apparently, there's a file called externaljob.ora, where you can specify the user account - see the Oracle forums link in my answer.

Comment: Ah yes -- I also recall it being a real pain -- I had to setup a cron job to regularly change ownership of files so that DBMS_Scheduler could access them.